# How to fix this tooltip alignment?

Tags: css, reactjs

how to fix this tooltip alignment. I want to show a tooltip on hover over on "info" link. But i am struggling to make it correctly aligned. If you can look at my code and provide a fix, i would really appreciate (if possible if you can add pagination support on tooltip if description is too big, that would also be helpfull)

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-voice-ug8fwm?file=/src/App.js

To render tooltip, tooltip.js is there

issue i am facing. I am trying to show the tooltip on the card itself:
[image]

Comment: doesn't a simple `z-index` fix this? Have you tired that?

Comment: How do yo mean "*I am trying to show the tooltip on the card itself*" ? Like an overlay?

Answer (score 0):

in file **tooltip.css**

- Add **z-index: 999;**
- Add **top: -250px;**
- Add **left: -40px;**

|

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  border-color: red;
  z-index: 999;
  top: -250px;
  left: -40px;
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to show the tooltip on top of individual card

Comment: try add   top: -250px;
  left: -40px; in  tooltip.css